# Hi i am trying to run a simple Odd even program but its giving me the error "identifier expected"

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to run a simple Odd even program but its giving me the error "identifier expected" program is as follows:

```
import.java.io.*;

public class OddevenbufferedReader {
  System.output.println("Enter a number to be checked as odd or even: ");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int num, output;
    num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    output = num % 2;
    if (output == 0) {
      System.out.println("Entered number is even");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Entered number is odd");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your enter key broken? Please remove all of those unnecessary blank lines.

Comment: Put your `System.out.println()` and `BufferedReader` inside a main method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.` between `import` and `java.io.*;`

```
import java.io.*;
```

and put the `System.output.println` and `BufferedReader br` lines inside your `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your program

1. Incorrect syntax for import.

   `import.java.io.*;`

should be

```
import java.io.*;
```

2. `System.output` should be corrected

   `System.output.println("Enter a number to be checked as odd or even: ");`

should be

```
System.out.println("Enter a number to be checked as odd or even: ");
```

3. Output statement should be present within the method block. And the exception thrown by the buffered reader should be handled i.e. update main method as

**main method**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number to be checked as odd or even: ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int num, output;
    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        output = num % 2;
        if (output == 0) {
            System.out.println("Entered number is even");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Entered number is odd");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks vivek  but i want to ask whether its necessary to use try and catch

Comment: Yes it is required to use try catch block. If you don't want to do that then you can propagate it to the caller method. Since main method is the caller method, it won't be wise to propagate it, cause the exception should be handled.